# how to get joined group list & their member info using XMPP?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, multiuserchat

To get Joined Room List i have tried:,

`getJoinedRooms(connection, "xmpptestuser1@server.com");// line:213`

```
Iterator<String> rooms = MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(conn, userJID);// line:689

    //System.out.println("ROOM:"+rooms);
      while (rooms.hasNext()) {

          System.out.println("Room list: "+new DiscoverItems.Item(rooms.next()).toString());;

      }
```

but, it gives NPE. So how can i fetch joined group List?
There is 1 joined group where 3 members are participants on my server Side.
**Logcat**:

```
 I/System.out(948): Room: join 
 W/System.err(948): java.lang.NullPointerException
 W/System.err(948): at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(MultiUserChat.java:180)
 W/System.err(948): at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient.getJoinedRooms(XMPPClient.java:689)
 W/System.err(948): at org.apache.android.xmpp.XMPPClient$4.onClick(XMPPClient.java:213)
 W/System.err(948): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
 W/System.err(948): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
 W/System.err(948): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 W/System.err(948): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 W/System.err(948): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 W/System.err(948): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 W/System.err(948): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 W/System.err(948): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 W/System.err(948): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 W/System.err(948): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 W/System.err(948): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To get RoomInfo i have tried:

```
RoomInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(conn,chatRoomName);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Number of occupants:" + info.getOccupantsCount());
```

How to fetch All members detail like their Nick Name, JID, owner in joined group?I have tried almost all the solution from SO.Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should also post the NPE and it's stacktrace.

Comment: @Flow It shows only one line when i call this method that `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Every exception in Java comes with an stacktrace, which is itself usually also logged, because it provides valuable information what exactly happened. aSmack and Android log exceptions with a full stacktrace, that usually spawns multiple lines in the log. Try to acquire this information and provide it. Otherwise it will be hard to help you, because "throws an NPE" isn't not enough information without some context.

Comment: I Have used try & catch to get this list. Simply it goes on Catch case & shows that one line.Have seen many questions on SO regarding NPE on joined list.but there is not any satisfied answer.

Comment: Why down Voted?Any reason.

Comment: Because your question does not contain enough information. You don't provide the NPE with stacktrace nor do you mention the used version of aSmack. As it stands, it's nearly impossible to help you and it won't be helpful to further users.

Comment: @Flow u can see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me also. What I did was I added a comma separated list of users when sending the invitation.

```
muc.invite(friendsJID, friendsJIDsList.toString());
```

And upon invitation Receive

```
public void invitationReceived(Connection conn, String room, String inviter, String reason, String password,
        Message message) {

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(reason.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

This list contains all the user Ids in group and Using it I get the Vcards of the users.
Hope this helps.